# Применение условия к Series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация

Есть код для отдельного столбца датафрейма:

```
for i in range(len(plan)): 
    if plan['ProducerGroup'][i]=='A':
        print('yes')
        plan['OTHER PRODUCTION COSTS'][i] = logistics_book['OTHER PRODUCTION COSTS'][0]
```

Однако он работает довольно долго на больших объемах данных.

Можно ли его как-то ускорить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
plan.loc[plan['ProducerGroup']=='A', 'OTHER PRODUCTION COSTS'] = \
    logistics_book['OTHER PRODUCTION COSTS'][0]
```

Цикл в данном случае не нужен.

---

Чтобы заполнить одинаковым значением по нескольким условиям:

```
plan.loc[plan['ProducerGroup'].isin(['A','B']), 'OTHER PRODUCTION COSTS'] = \
    logistics_book['OTHER PRODUCTION COSTS'][0]
```

Comment: а для двух и более условий такое может сработать?
где plan['ProducerGroup']=='A', plan['ProductGroup']=='B'

Comment: @marcevgen, это зависит от деталей. Если по нескольким условиям заполнять одним и тем же значением, то сработает, а если разными то нет. В последнем случае лучше задать отдельный вопрос с небольшим примером входных и выходных данных.